# is there any way to connect or to integrate Mule Github Connector to Bitbucket? or is there Bitbucket Connector?

Tags: java, github, mule, bitbucket

how to integrate Mule Github Connector to Bitbucket Account? or check-out repository or add comment to a repository from Bitbucket using Mule Github Connector? or is there any Mule Bitbucket Connector? please help me with this stuff :D

Comment: or any suggestions :D

Answer (score 0):

No the Github connector directly uses the Github HTTP APIs.

The Atlassian Stash connector can connect to 'Bitbucket Server': https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/atlassian-stash-connector?types=connector&searchTerm=bitbuc&sortBy=name#!/atlassian-stash-connector?searchTerm=stash

There is also an old Git connector that uses the git protocol that allows connecting via git to any git repo, bitbucket, github etc: https://github.com/mulesoft/git-connector